# How to use mathematical operators on WMI query results?

Tags: wmi, wmi-query

I am doing some scripting for my company using [BGInfo](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897557) and am trying to figure out how to take a result of a WMI query and apply mathematical operators to it. For example, I am running the query:

```
SELECT AdapterRAM FROM Win32_VideoController
```

which evaluates to

```
268435456 (bytes)
```

However, I want this value to take the form of MB, so I want to divide this result by  1,048,576 to get

```
256 MB
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

The `WQL` (the language used by the `WMI`) is only a subset of the SQL language, and doesn't support arithmetical operators, for more info you can check the [`WQL documentation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394606%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) .

Answer (score 0):

As @RRUZ mentions, there is no support for arithmetic operators in WQL. However, in scirpting languages such as PowerShell, you can use the conversion units or multipliers to change the value from bytes to MB.

For example,

```
$adapterRAM = Get-WMIObject -Query "SELECT AdapterRAM FROM Win32_VideoController"
$adapterRAM.AdapterRAM/1MB
```

Updating the answer based on the comment below:

```
(Get-WMIObject -Query "SELECT AdapterRAM FROM Win32_VideoController").AdapterRam/1MB
```

If the above query results in multiple instances of Win32_VideoController, you have to index into the right instance. For example,

```
(Get-WMIObject -Query "SELECT AdapterRAM FROM Win32_VideoController")[0].AdapterRam/1MB
```

Comment: i would try this, but I am making the query from BGinfo.exe which prohibits me from setting the result of the query to a variable of any kind

Comment: @MattHintzke: You could use the **VBScript file** option instead of **WMI Query** to execute VBScript code with variables and stuff. You'll have to convert ravikanth's PowerShell example to VBScript though.